# Exception in thread "Thread-60" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path

Tags: java, maven, opencv

Attempting to build sikuli-slides-1.5.0 with the command "mvn clean install", I am getting the above referenced stack trace.  I am using Windows 7 and have attempted the instructions I have come across for various solutions proposed on here to no avail. My Path and CLASSPATH variables for both user and system defined variables include:

"C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin"

and I have restarted my machine multiple times.

In addition, I have added javacv.jar, javacv.windows-x86.jar, javacv.windows-x86_64.jar to my project's build path and have javacv-0.9.jar in my pom.xml.  I have also included javacpp-0.9.jar in my pom as well.  I can visually see all of the above referenced jars on my build path and can import the jniopencv_core into any of my classes.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  While executing the JUnit test AutomationExecutorExceptionTest.java, the test fails and creates an orphaned java.exe process that must be manually shut down.

The full stack trace is listed below.

> Exception in thread "Thread-60" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in >java.library.path
>          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
>          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
>          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:535)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:410)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:353)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.(opencv_core.java:10)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractIplImage.create(openc
>   v_core.java:909)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractIplImage.createFrom(o
>   pencv_core.java:999)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractIplImage.createFrom(o
>   pencv_core.java:971)
>          at org.bytedeco.javacpp.helper.opencv_core$AbstractIplImage.createFrom(o
>   pencv_core.java:968)
>          at org.sikuli.core.cv.ImagePreprocessor.createGrayscale(ImagePreprocesso
>   r.java:43)
>          at org.sikuli.core.search.TemplateMatcher.findMatchesByGrayscaleAtOrigin
>   alResolution(TemplateMatcher.java:71)
>          at org.sikuli.api.ImageTarget.getUnorderedMatches(ImageTarget.java:127)
>          at org.sikuli.api.DefaultTarget.doFindAll(DefaultTarget.java:128)
>          at org.sikuli.api.DefaultScreenRegion.findAll(DefaultScreenRegion.java:7
>   4)
>          at org.sikuli.slides.api.sikuli.CrossSearchStrategy.testHypotheses(Cross
>   SearchStrategy.java:85)
>          at org.sikuli.slides.api.sikuli.CrossSearchStrategy.perform(CrossSearchS
>   trategy.java:39)
>          at org.sikuli.slides.api.sikuli.ContextImageTarget.doFindAll(ContextImag
>   eTarget.java:122)
>          at org.sikuli.api.DefaultScreenRegion._find(DefaultScreenRegion.java:88)
>
> ```
>    at org.sikuli.api.DefaultScreenRegion.find(DefaultScreenRegion.java:80)
>    at org.sikuli.slides.api.actions.TargetAction.execute(TargetAction.java:
> ```
>
> 26)
>          at org.sikuli.slides.api.actions.RetryAction.execute(RetryAction.java:51
>   )
>          at org.sikuli.slides.api.actions.ParallelAction$Worker.run(ParallelActio
>   n.java:35)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: that "no jniopencv_cor e" is an error because of your typing or because of the import? (it should be "no jniopencv_core")

Comment: That is correct.  I copied it from my command prompt.

Comment: Can you please post the import you have used?

Comment: What is your classpath?

Comment: You should use [these two](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|opencv) I would suggest more the `nu.pattern` one because is more close to C++ version of OpenCV and I think it is more optimized

Comment: @sop I am not using an import. I was just demonstrating that it was in fact detected within my build path.  The package com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core

Comment: @DavidPostill my classpath and path variable include: C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\bin.  I am working on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: In which directory is `javacv.jar` located? Normally `jar` files are in a `lib` directory ...

Comment: @DavidPostill C:\Users\<username>\workspace\sikuli-slides\lib I created the lib directory and pasted each jar file in there then added them in Eclipse to my project's build path.

Comment: Is `C:\Users\<username>\workspace\sikuli-slides\lib` in your classpath?

Comment: No.  Am I supposed to include this to my system classpath?  I thought I was only supposed to add it to the project build path.

Comment: @DavidPostill I tried adding it to my path.  I still get the same failure.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: This is a runtime error, not a build time error, right? If so, try to run your application with Maven as shown here: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/opencv

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace contains the following line:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-60" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_cor e in java.library.path at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
```

Notice the <kbd>space</kbd> between `jniopencv_cor` and `e`?

One of your configuration files contain a <kbd>space</kbd> where it shouldn't.

Comment: That was a copy error.  I copied the stack trace from my command line and the text wrapped around.

Comment: Then I think `jniopencv_core` is **not** in your classpath, or is incorrectly specified somewhere in your build process.

Comment: Do I need to specifically add each individual *.dll to my classpath?  I have Path and CLASSPATH set at both the user and system properties level pointing to the vc10\bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

The directions are highly confusing for the javacv files.  The issue was that I had to actually explode the contents of the jar file and expose the DLLs in the directory.  The instructions packaged with the jars of javacv instructed me to simply place the binaries on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding the following dependency in my Maven project for Sikuli Slides 1.5.1:

GroupId: org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets
AritfactId: opencv
Version: 2.4.9-0.9
Type: jar
Classifier: windows-x86_64

In my case I was using Windows 7 64-bit. After adding this dependency I was able to successfully build Sikuli Slides.